# Why is the ul element being below the other ul elements due to difference in children?

Tags: html, css

I have this `footer` menu that I've made consisting of `ul` and `li`, one of them which, only has *two* elements (children) within, whereas the other *two* `ul` elements have more. Now, here's the issue; as I line them to be `display: inline-block;` the `ul` with the least children is below the level of the other *two* `ul` elements.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this without a padding or a margin cheat?

Here's an example in a [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/qqat9o1p/1/)

As you can see, the *feature* menu is obviously below the other `ul` menus, which leaves me yet again with the question; why is this happening and how can I fix it?

If the code is necessary again to this question, I'd be more than happy to comply.

Comment: You need a [mcve] *in your question*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display: inline-block` goes hand in hand with `vertical-align`, for which the default value is `baseline`.

You will want to set `vertical-align: top` on the `.menu` class here. To be safe, it's good to always specify vertical align whenever you use inline block, because you'll rarely want it to be baseline.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. So the default by standard on `vertical-align` is `baseline` which makes the elements start from down to up. Hence, by putting `top` instead, it makes the element order from up to down. Thank you very much for this quick and understandable answer!

Comment: Just to clarify, you have to put the vertical-align: top attribute into the .menu class in your CSS. It will work there.

Comment: Yeah, did that. Works absolutely magnificent. Thanks anyhow for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Thats because your first item list contains only two items the other two are containing three elements. In your project they align with the bottom. Now you could add a third element or change your css so its align at the top.

Comment: That was exactly what I did at first, however, as I changed it due to not needing it, it looked badly. Hence, this question. Anyhow, thanks for the optimism for helping, Micheal!

Comment: perfect ;) now I am really relieved ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `vertical-align: top` like:

```css
.footer {
 width: 100%;
 height: 30em;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #f7f8fc;
}
.option {
 display: flex;
 position: relative;
}
.menu-wrapper {
 width: 50%;
 position: relative;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%);
}
.menu {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0 1em;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.menu ul {
 padding: 1em 0;
}
.menu li {
 padding: 0.5em 0;
}
.menu h6 {
 font-size: 0.8em;
 font-weight: 600;
 color: #7c919c;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 0.5px;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.menu a {
 color: #717585;
 font-size: 0.85em;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.menu a:hover {
 color: #ba226c;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
   <div class="container customize">
    <div class="option">
     <div class="menu-wrapper">
      <div class="feature menu">
       <ul>
        <li>
         <h6>Feature</h6>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="about menu">
       <ul>
        <li>
         <h6>About</h6>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Explore</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="support menu">
       <ul>
        <li>
         <h6>Support</h6>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </footer>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Surely did, as Matis said in his answer. Thank you anyhow! :)

Comment: @JamesSnowy My bad. I was late tough. Wasted time making the snippet... :)

Comment: Haha, appreciate the enthusiasm though! ;)

Comment: @JamesSnowy My pleasure!